# Sharing Ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I have packages of Ansible roles that I would like to import into a project.

If I organise them by subdirectory I run into problems relating to dependency relative paths

i.e the shared role needs to know its relative location of where it would be installed if it uses meta dependencies

I would like to be able to just reference everything to the directory the playbook is being run from though this doesn't work

```
roles/roleA/meta
 ---
 dependencies:
   - { role: "{{ playbook_dir }}/roles/shared_roles/roleB"}

roles/shared_roles/roleB
...
```

I've tried multiple options and running out of ideas.

I looked into  roles-path http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#roles-path

Though I don't really want to have to uniquely name all roles as they ought to be namespaced / grouped.

Thanks

Comment: The shared roles are packaged by Maven currently and get built into a directory. If I reference that directory in all the shared roles then dependencies resolve. This seems to be a solution. I'll update with an answer if it does work... nobody answers my questions anyway so its not like anybody is reading this

Answer (score 1):

You could basically use `ansible-galaxy` to install the roles within `~/.ansible/roles/` path.

The path of `.ansible` in my `macOS machine` is in: `~/.ansible/roles/`

All you need to do is just create a `requirements.yml` file which looks something like this:

```
- src: git+https://<githubURL-Master-role>.git
  scm: git
  name: Master-role

- src: git+https://<githubURL-dependent1-role>.git
  scm: git
  name: dependent1-role

- src: git+https://<githubURL-dependent2-role>.git
  scm: git
  name: dependent2-role
```

Run this command to install your roles in `~/.ansible/roles/` path:

`sudo ansible-galaxy -vvv -r install requirements.yml`

This will basically set your roles in the `~/.ansible/roles/` path. To understand it better please follow this documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html.

and then, like you have already mentioned, you should add all the dependent roles in your `##path/master-role/meta/main.yml` file even before executing the `anisble-galaxy` command, in-order to execute the dependent roles before the `master-role`, when you run your master-role playbook.

The `##path/master-role/meta/main.yml` file looks something like this:

```
galaxy_info:
  author: Jithendra
  description: blah...blah...blah
  min_ansible_version: 1.2
  galaxy_tags:'[]'
dependencies:
  - { role: 'Master-role, when: blah == "true"'}         #when condition is optional
  - { role: 'dependent1-role, when blah == "false"'}
  - { role: 'dependent2-role, when blah == "false"'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by enforcing that all shared modules reference the name of the shared directory in all dependencies.

I wanted to leave this up to the calling project and hoped that dependencies would be relative to the role directory.

The solution works though and provides namespacing so I can include multiple roles with the same name as long as they are in separate directories.

I now have a project that includes 3 separate packages of roles

```
 PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
staging : ok=214  changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Its all built using Maven, each shared group being a maven dependency. If anybody reads this and it helps i'll share the structure / poms etc.

Comment: Will move my questions to the google groups in future... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ansible-project